# how to position the buttons in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, web

I am building a website using jquery mobile. I am trying to position buttons and also resize them.  this is what i have so far. thanks in advance for any help. let me know if there is any other way to approach this. my problem is those two buttons does not appear on giving positions.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#ui-1").css({'position':'relative','left':'400.0px','top':'5.0px','width':'450px','height':'250px',});

$("#ui-1.ui-btn-text").css({'font-family':'"Calibri","Arial","Sans Serif"','font-size':'1.75em','color':'black','text-align':'center','wordwrap':'normal','text-shadow':'1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF'});

$("#ui-2").css({'position':'relative','left':'15.0px','top':'-10.0px','width':'450px','height':'250px',});

$("#ui-2.ui-btn-text").css({'font-family':'"Calibri","Arial","Sans Serif"','font-size':'1.75em','color':'black','text-align':'center','wordwrap':'normal','text-shadow':'1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF'});


</script>


</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   

  <a id="ui-1" href="wines.html" data-role="button"   data-theme="c" > 
   <img src="image1.png" width="200" height="200 "> <br/> 
   Wines </a>
   <a id="ui-2" href="wines.html" data-role="button"   data-theme="c" > 
   <img src="image1.png" width="200" height="200 "> <br/> 
   Wines </a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```